# Why is it I am getting Listening failure when trying to listen out for potential connections

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client-server, winsock

Here is my code(the port number is 2222):
I seem to get `listen(sock_LISTEN, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)` as true and therefore failing but cant understand why?
please enlighten me

```
//Create Socket Structure
sockaddr_in address;
int AddressSize = sizeof(address);

//Create Sockets
SOCKET sock_LISTEN; //listen for incoming connection
SOCKET sock_CONNECTION; //active if connection found
int test;
                        //socket Arguments: AF_INET = internet domain,
                        //SOCK_STREAM = connection oriented with TCP 
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); //Set IP
address.sin_family = AF_INET;
address.sin_port = htons(port); // logical port

sock_LISTEN = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

if (sock_LISTEN == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    cout << "\nSocket Failure\n" << WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
}

//binding the socket
bind(sock_LISTEN, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(address));

//listen without limits
if (listen(sock_LISTEN, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    cout << "\nListening failure " << WSAGetLastError();
}
```

Comment: And what is the reason given by `WSAGetLastError`?

Comment: You should check the return value from `bind` -- it's far more likely to fail than `listen` so the error you're seeing may just be a red herring.

Comment: WSAGetLastError is returning 10022

Comment: How do I check the return value from bind? I tried storing bind(sock_LISTEN, (sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in)); into an integer and then a simple if statement to check to see if it was equal to SOCKET_ERROR

Comment: Thank you so much for the help its was bind....